# Java: Best way to retrieve values in List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I would like to know the best way to retrieve the elements of a list inside a list.

```
            List<Object> totalsList = new ArrayList<Object>();      
            Map<String, Object> grandTotalsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();             
            List<Map<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            Map<String, String> lineItemsMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();      
            lineItemsMap1.put("amount", "$70.00");
            lineItemsMap1.put("period", "Monthly");

            Map<String, String> lineItemsMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();      
            lineItemsMap2.put("amount", "$55.00");
            lineItemsMap2.put("period", "Bi-Monthly");

            items.add(lineItemsMap1);
            items.add(lineItemsMap2);

            grandTotalsMap.put("section" , "total per pay period amounts");
            grandTotalsMap.put("title", "You'r amount");
            grandTotalsMap.put("lineItems", items);
```

**
  // I'm expecting output as: I want to create a new Map and put key-values like below:

```
    {
    amount: $70.00, 
    period: Monthly,
    },

    {
    amount: $55.00, 
    period: Bi-Monthly,

    }
```

**

Comment: you can use `lambda` inside `lambda`

Comment: `ArrayLists` have a `arrayListObject.get(int index)` method that can be used to get the individual elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using `items.get(int index)` will return a HashMap corresponding to the location in the array that map is stored.  For instance, `items.get(0)` would return your the first map you added (lineItemsMap1) while `items.get(1)` would return the second map you added (lineItemsMap2).

Once you have the correct map you are looking for, you can then call the `HashMap.get(String columnName)` to retrieve the value you have stored.

Two different ways to access the information stored in your ArrayList are as follows:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = items.get(0);
String amount = map.get("amount"); // This will return '$70.00'
String period = map.get("period"); // This will return 'Monthly'
```

OR

```
String amount = items.get(0).get("amount"); // Returning '$70.00'
String period = items.get(0).get("period"); // Returning 'Monthly'
```

If you are looking to create a new map with these values, you can either store them in local variables (like done above) and then add the variables into the map when creating it like:

`HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
newMap.put("newAmount", amount);`

Or you can add the values by directly accessing the ArrayList when creating the map:

```
newMap.put("newAmount", items.get(0).get("amount"));
```

Hope this helps!